# Meaning of regularity theory inspired by certain people

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the field of partial differential equations (PDE) I recently read multiply times that the proof strategy is "of the De Giorgi type regularity in the sense of $C^{1,\alpha}$-regularity by Uraltseva". I know De Giorgi and I know Uraltseva but I don't know exactly what the above means. Could somebody explain in a "few" words what the idea of De Giorgi (and Uraltseva) was? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you attach a link to a paper/PDF/book that this paragraph is from? It's okay (at least for me) if the language is not English.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Yes, for example this one:
Remarks on Holder continuity for parabolic
equations and convergence to global attractors - by Le Dung

Unfortunately I cannot insert the link to the pdf here since it is far too long in terms of characters!